# Listpicker Multiple selection and DisplayMemberPath

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7

I have a collection of my custom entity that is bound to the listpicker using the `ItemsSource` property. I also have selection mode set to `Multiple` so I have a checkbox with each item in the FullMode picker. This picking works, fine, and I can easily access all objects that were picked thru code. What I'm having troubles with is the `DisplayMemberPath`. I want to display something more friendly than the namespace of the object that is selected. Perhaps a count of selected items, or a comma separated list of the values selected.

Unfortunately, 'AccountId' doesn't work when I set the SelectionMode="Multiple". Single mode is fine. Any ideas?

```
<toolkit:ListPicker 
    x:Name="accountlistpicker"
    Grid.Row="0" Header="accounts" 
    SelectionMode="Multiple"
    DisplayMemberPath="AccountId"
    ItemsSource="{Binding AllAccounts}" 
    FullModeItemTemplate="{StaticResource AccountsListPickerFullItemTemplate}" />
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to assign function to `SummaryForSelectedItemsDelegate` that will process how summary string will looks like.

Check [this](http://attowares.com/blog/tag/listpicker/) for learn more

Comment: I wish I could give you 10 upvotes. Thank you! The naming makes sense now, I guess. But before, I wouldn't have thought twice about skipping over that delegate.