# Set text on chosen ListPicker value in WP7

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, listpicker

Hi im creating a WP7app where you can choose categories using a listpicker.

```
 <toolkit:ListPicker Header="Choose Categories" 
                                    SelectionMode="Multiple" 
                                    FullModeHeader="CATEFORIES"
                                    x:Name="ListPickerCategories"
                                    CacheMode="BitmapCache"                                
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                    Margin="24,482,0,0"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                    Width="401"                                
                                    Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                    ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}">                
                </toolkit:ListPicker>
```

[image]

When choosing categories I want to be able to specify what values will be shown above in the box. Right now the default is to always show the the first chosen value.

How do you specify this?

Comment: Use some like this Header="{Binding ElementName=ListPickerCategories path selecteditem.value}"

Comment: Duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8670898/listpicker-multiple-selection-and-displaymemberpath

Answer (score 2):

Change `ListPickerMode` property to `Expanded` then set `ItemCountThreshold` to count of items you need show.

More information you can find [here](http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/listpicker-for-wp7-in-depth)

Comment: ItemCountThreshold is read only in WP7.1 i know there is no indecation on the version used but your answer does not solve the issue anyway. Thanks